# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is undefined amazon-cognito-identity-js user.completeNewPasswordChallenge

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

all. Can anyone help me understand why I am getting a Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is undefined in the below code? It does not make it to the on success or on failure clauses.

```
const onSubmitPasscode = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (passwordFirst !== passwordSecond) {
      alert('the two inputs provided are not the same');
    } else {
      const user = new CognitoUser({
        Username: email,
        Pool: UserPool
      });

      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: email,
        Password: password
      });

      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onFailure: (err) => {
          console.error('onFailure:', err);
        },
        newPasswordRequired: () => {
          user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(passwordFirst, {
            onFailure: (err) => {
              console.error('onFailure:', err);
            },
            onSuccess: (result) => {
              console.log(passwordFirst);
              console.log('call result: ', result);
              navigate('dashboard');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that `authenticateUser` succeeded without requiring a new password? And since there is no `onSuccess` callback provided, you got a callback is undefined error?

Answer (score 0):

Define an `onSuccess` function for `authenticateUser`:

```js
user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
  onSuccess: (result) => {
    console.log(result);
  },
  onFailure: (err) => {
    console.error('onFailure:', err);
  },
  newPasswordRequired: () => {
    user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(passwordFirst, {
      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.error('onFailure:', err);
      },
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        console.log(passwordFirst);
        console.log('call result: ', result);
        navigate('dashboard');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Also, based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js), `newPasswordRequired` takes a function whose signature is different from what you are providing. So I think what you might want is really:

```js
user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
  onSuccess: (result) => {
    console.log(passwordFirst);
    console.log('call result: ', result);
    navigate('dashboard');
  }
  onFailure: (err) => {
    console.error('onFailure:', err);
  },
  newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {
    /*whatever you want to do when new password is required*/
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, the password change completes. The only issue is the user is not redirected, the error pops up that I indicated above. So it works - but I'm missing something